# Sending myself an email with search word from site search (tipuesearch) using MVC4

Tags: email, view, actionresult, silent

I am using "[tipuesearch](http://www.tipue.com/search/)" for search option in my site. I am trying to better index my site by learning what visitors are typing in the search textbox. To do that, I am thinking of sending myself an email with each search with the typed keywords.

I managed to perform the email actionResult with the keywords but the problem is that the "tipuesearch" presents the results in the same page (which is good for me) and actionResult requires a "return view" that loads a view.

Is there a way to retrieve the keywords from the textbox and email them to myself without effecting the user or without redirecting to a different page? 
something like silent email sending or background sending...

Thank you!